# certificate-transparency how to query certificates for a domain

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-transparency

I want to get a list of ssl certificates used by all fqdn of a domain name. So, we can imagine that I search **google.com** certificates. I will get the **google.com** and **www.google.com** certificate but I want also get **checkout.google.com** certificate and others.

For this I can use this page which use certificate transparency : https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/ct/#domain=google.com&incl_exp=false&incl_sub=true

This page give a github repository : https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency

I cloned it and install all things to use Python dashboard. But I don't know how to query the database to find all **google.com** certificates ?

There is not public API available, not database filled...

Do you know a way to get all FQDN for a domain name by using certificate transparency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but in case others run across stumbleupon this...

https://crt.sh exists now and you can query all the certificate domains they have observed.  Also facebook has a email subscription service you can get notified for new certificates for specific domains. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/ct/.

Comment: Thank you. This answer provides good links. I also use Google to get Certificates : https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/ct/?hl=fr